# How to run action first, then conditionally target in xstate

Tags: conditional-statements, state, target, state-machine, xstate

I am using xState app machines and I am finding myself needing to do things in sequence. Below when I fir NAV_OK, I want it to **run the action 'run-search' first, then after it runs, I want it to focus automatically on the correct element based on some guard/condition.** It seems to be choosing them instead. Unfortunately I cannot move the action 'run_search' into each target block, as I need it to run before it deals with those.

```
 NAV_OK: [
                //run the search and return products/videos
                { actions: 'run_search' },
                {

                  //if products exists focus on that swimlane
                  target: 'products',
                  cond: (ctx) => ctx.products > 0

                },
                {
                  //if videos exists focus on that swimlane
                  target: 'videos',
                   cond: (ctx) => ctx.videos > 0

                }

              ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating another state where I handled the run_search then I used a weird xstate '' thing called transient transition.

```
newState: {
            id: 'newState',
            entry: 'run_search',
            on: {
             '': [
                {
                    cond:(ctx) => ctx.products > 0,
                    target:'products',
                },
                {
                    cond:(ctx) => ctx.videos > 0,
                    target: 'videos',
                                    
                },
                {
                    target: 'idle'
                }
               ]
              }
             }
```

Comment: You can use `always: { ... }` instead of `on: { '': { ... } }`

Comment: Also, sorry if it seems weird, it's not an XState thing, it's a state machine thing (also known as an epsilon transition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_transition